# React Native : state is getting undefined inside useCallBack hook function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-hooks

State is getting undefined inside the useCallBack hook I think it is not getting scope to the state variable

```
const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState()
const selectLocationHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedLocation({
        lat: event.nativeEvent.coordinate.latitude,
        lng: event.nativeEvent.coordinate.longitude
    })
    console.log('set location', selectedLocation)
}

const saveLocationPickerHandler = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('saveLocation', selectedLocation)
    if (!selectedLocation) {
        return;
    }
    props.navigation.navigate('DeliveryLocation', { pickedLocation: selectedLocation })
}, [])
```

set location Iam getting Object {
  "lat": 37.775030512686214,
  "lng": -122.4273883345241,
}

where as savelocation is undefined in console

Answer (score 10):

You need to provide `selectedLocation` as a dependency. Else the callback will not update if the state changes.

```js
const saveLocationPickerHandler = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('saveLocation', selectedLocation)
    if (!selectedLocation) {
        return;
    }
    props.navigation.navigate('DeliveryLocation', { pickedLocation: selectedLocation })
}, [selectedLocation])
```

If you provide an empty array as dependency the useCallback function will always have the initial state and never update (selectedLocation). 
This is the same behaviour useEffect has